# Database backup with another server using SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have active Server A and standby Server B and B is replicating data from Server A.

I'm using SQL Server 2005 enterprise edition.

When Server A is failed, the application server is programmed to route traffic to Server B.

Then Server B becomes active server and Server A becomes standby server.

To turn Server A to be active server, the data modification when Server A failed in Server B needs to replicate back to Server A.

I don't want to over load in active server.

I'm thinking to use pull transactional replication method for replication.

But I want to know what is the best method for doing above operations because this is the first time doing this operation for me.

Comment: THis is probably better suited to be asked on [Serverfault.com](http://Serverfault.com) or [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) since it's really more of a sysadmin/DBA question - not really **programming-related**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered utilizing `database mirroring` instead?

Of course... you'll end up needing a witness server, but unlike replication, there is less work for everyone. No scripts are needed to make sure that the previously failed server has the most updated data.